# Browser Compatibility in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

My GWT project works well in Firefox 9.0.1, but in other browsers it doesn't, even I set this

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8,ie8,safari,opera" />
```

in `filename.gwt.xml`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try to compile code, You will get idea through compile error. Once compile successfully, so it will work well.

Comment: What is not working? How come we know? Just remove this property and compile it again. Everything will work until and unless you are using some native or browser specific code.

Answer (score 1):

You can force Document mode to "Quirks", by writing the host page as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/> 
</head>
<body>
..
```

Two of my Gwt webapps work perfectly with the solution above. And [here are notes from the official](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideIE9.html) for your reference.

Comment: "unless you are sure what you are doing" - When does anyone ever know that? And is there ever a case where the opposite is true, where IE9 is different from IE10-pretending-to-be-IE9 is different from IE11-pretending-to-be-IE9? (hint: yes, IE is bad at pretending) For a very brief introduction to IE not emulating what it claims to be emulating, try the horse's mouth: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx